# Power down current

Tags: analog, vlsi, leakage-current

I'm designing a Variable Gain Amplifier (VGA) for a course project. I'm using Cadence CMOS 180nm technology. One of the requirements is to find the power down current through simulation. I searched on google about the meaning of power down current and found that it's the leakage current when the supple is off.

Does anyone of you have any idea of how to simulate the power down current?

Comment: If the power is removed, current is zero.

Comment: You need to have a more detailed idea of what the "power down" state of your amplifier *actually* is. It is like an empty phrase in your question.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Iddq?

Answer (score 1):

No, power down current is not the current with the supply off.  That would always be 0.  It is the current the device draws when told to shut down, but with the capability to come back up when told to do so.  In other words, this is the current when it shuts off its own supply to the main operating part, leaving enough circuitry on so that it can turn this supply back on.

This is usually the standby current of the part that needs to remain on.  Generally you use a single FET in series with the supply to the main operating section, so the leakage of that FET is added to the standby current.  The leakage of a single FET is usually not the issue, though.  It's the multiple leakage paths thru the static digital circuitry that add up to the power down current.